# Increase Pop Swipe Range iOS

Tags: ios

Facebook, Instagram, and Twitter, these huge applications allow users to pop the screens with swipe gesture easily by increasing the swipe start range from right/leading.

Out-of-the-box, iOS allows us to do such, by default. And when adding a custom back button, that gesture is usually removed, but can be brought back by:

```
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
```

The question is, how to increase the start range? For reference, the mentioned apps above have significant longer swipe start range than the default one.